# Docking an Encapsulated Control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, windows-forms-designer, docking

I have an encapsulated control in a derived `TabPage`, and I am having trouble docking it to the form `MainForm` that contains the derived `TabPage`.

I've added the `TabPage` and the control correctly, and they are showing up on `MainForm`. However, the control is not correctly docked (style: fill). You can verify this by resizing the form.

I've set the property `_control.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill` and `_control.Anchor = Left | Right | Top | Bottom` in the derived `TabPage`'s constructor.

Below is the sample of the code:

```
public class DerivedTab : TabPage {
    public DerivedTab(){
        ...
        _control= new BrightIdeasSoftware.TreeListView();
        this.Controls.Add(this._control);
        _control.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom;
        _control.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        ...
    }
}
```

In the `MainForm`, this is the function that creates the derived tab in run-time:

```
    private DerivedTab CreateTab(string name)
    {
        DerivedTab tab = new DerivedTab(this, name);
        tab.SuspendLayout();

        MainTab.Controls.Add(tab);
        return tab;
    }
```

Anyways, I generated this code using Visual Studio Designer, and the control docks correctly. I, then, created a class for the tabpage (since I will need many and varying number of these tabs) and copied everything relates to tabpage to the `CreateTab` function. I moved anything relates to the the property of the tabpage into its constructor. I encapsulated the control in the derived `TabPage` and moved everything related to the control in the derived tabpage.

So, what I am missing? Is it possible to dock the encapsulated control without implementing an eventhandler function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my own problem. ResumeLayout has to be called after the TabControl adds the TabPage for the TabPage to dock properly.

```
private DerivedTab CreateTab(string name)
{
    DerivedTab tab = new DerivedTab(this, name);
    tab.SuspendLayout();

    MainTab.Controls.Add(tab);
    tab.ResumeLayout();
    return tab;
}
```